# Undo and redo functionality broken

Tags: visual-studio-code

can someone explain when and why the undo and redo history will clear themselves? It seems like just switching windows will clear the history, seems to be no logic to why. There has been multiple occasions where i've lost code due to the redo history being cleared for no apparent reason.

Comment: Sounds like a good reason for a bug report, no?

Answer (score 1):

As I'm sure is the case with most editors, the Undo and Redo buffers for a file in Visual Studio Code are "cleared" as soon as you've closed said file.

Furthermore, the Redo buffer for a file, **is cleared as soon as you've added more text to that file**.